# Hooking into wp_export filter for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

I'm working with a CPT which has 5 taxonomies (tags, not categories).  I am attempting to use the `wp_export` filter.

The issue I am experiencing is when the filter is running: it appears to run it against the `wp_posts` table AND the `wp_users` table.

So, when the query runs against the `wp_posts` table; all is good.  We are filtering the posts based on the `post_date` column; which exists on that table.

However, when our same filter ALSO runs on the `wp_users` table; we fail because the `wp_users` table does not contain a `post_date` column.

Here is what WP seems to do (from my experience with this) with our custom query filter:

1. WP is running our updated filter against the `wp_posts` table.  SUCCESS -> all posts are listed matching our query.
2. WP is running our updated filter against the `wp_users` table.  FAIL -> `wp_users` table does not contain a `post_date` column.

WP then does the same thing against the:
* `wp_terms` -> FAIL
* `wp_postmeta` -> FAIL
* `wp_comments` -> FAIL

Here is the (modified) query I am currently running - hooked to `wp_export`:

```
function reviews_query( $query ) {
  $args = array( 'start_date' => false, 'end_date' => false );
  if ( $_REQUEST['emember_tickets_start_date'] || $_REQUEST['emember_tickets_end_date'] ) {
      $args['start_date'] = $_REQUEST['emember_tickets_start_date'] ;
      $args['end_date'] = $_REQUEST['emember_tickets_end_date'] ;
  }

  global $wpdb;

  if ($args['start_date'] && $args['end_date']) {
      $start_date = isset($args['start_date']) ? date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime($args['start_date'])) : '';
      $end_date = isset($args['end_date']) ? date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($args['end_date']))) : '';
      $query .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_date BETWEEN %s AND %s", $start_date, $end_date );
  }

  elseif ( $args['start_date'] && !$args['end_date'] )  {
      $start_date = isset($args['start_date']) ? date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime($args['start_date'])) : '';
      $query .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_date >= %s", $start_date );
  }

  elseif ( $args['end_date'] && !$args['start_date'] ) {
      $end_date = isset($args['end_date']) ? date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($args['end_date']))) : '';
      $query .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_date < %s", $end_date );
  }

  //var_export($query);
  return $query;
}
```

My question...
Is it possible to keep our 'updated custom query' from running against all these other tables where it is failing... and run it ONLY against the `wp_posts` table?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I am being an idiot, but I can't find a `wp_export` hook. What provides that hook? Do you have a link to the source?